# Query planner showing identical row counts for MCV and non-MCV values with a partial expression index of a JSONB field

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan

I have the following table in PostgreSQL 13.3:

```sql
CREATE TABLE node (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  meta jsonb NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

And there's index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX node_meta_group_owner_uuid ON node USING BTREE ((meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid'));
```

(**UPDATE:** This index was actually partial, having clause `... WHERE meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid' IS NOT NULL`. This lead to the resolution that reads in the comments and the answer.)

The table has ~20M rows. I've run `VACUUM ANALYZE`.

Number of rows:

```
db=> SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE 'node_meta_group_owner_uuid';

-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+---------------------------
oid                 | 19449180
relname             | node_meta_group_owner_uuid
...
relpages            | 29815
reltuples           | 2.0835164e+07
...
```

Index stats:

```sql
db=> SELECT * FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'node_meta_group_owner_uuid';

schemaname             | public
tablename              | node_meta_group_owner_uuid
attname                | expr
inherited              | f
null_frac              | 0
avg_width              | 40
n_distinct             | 812466
most_common_vals       | {48d11628-bfe9-4512-97e0-b308b7b5ac76,6a6b937f-c17c-49cb-a55a-e5346fe4ecfe,949b6f2c-2aae-42e0-a237-58cac017c6a0,f1792b9d-78a1-4811-a2e6-61532b689d07,...}
most_common_freqs      | {0.00024385618,0.00020321348,0.00013547565,0.00012192809,...}
histogram_bounds       | {00000c34-0cfa-443c-bbfd-75a7df972dde,028ca2c2-6bea-4fdd-a19c-c8b1976e96be,0518044d-41bf-40da-9bc6-763b0883d65b,07b677e7-747e-438e-a6fb-2c4af7c1c435,...}
correlation            | -0.00047400856
most_common_elems      | 
most_common_elem_freqs | 
elem_count_histogram   |
```

Now, given an entry (in `WHERE`) which does not exist in MCV list:

```
db=> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid' = 'a';
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=405494.13..405494.14 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Index Scan using node_meta_group_owner_uuid on node t1  (cost=0.56..405233.93 rows=104081 width=0)
         Index Cond: ((meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid'::text) = 'a'::text)
(3 rows)
```

The Index Scan estimates to find **104081** rows.

With entry that *does* exist in the MCV list:

```
db=> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid' = '48d11628-bfe9-4512-97e0-b308b7b5ac76';
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=405494.13..405494.14 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Index Scan using node_meta_group_owner_uuid on node t1  (cost=0.56..405233.93 rows=104081 width=0)
         Index Cond: ((meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid'::text) = '48d11628-bfe9-4512-97e0-b308b7b5ac76'::text)
(3 rows)
```

The estimate for the amount of rows is the same. I would have expected the row estimate in this one to be different (`0.00024385618 * 2.0816244e+07 = ~5076` to be precise) as there's clearly an entry for it in the MCV list.

Why is querying with the MCV value not returning different row cost estimate? Is this related to JSONB?

I do understand PostgreSQL does not collect statistics JSONB column, but the expression index does.

Comment: What is the true n_distinct for the expression? What is the stats target?  Can you post the entirely of `most_common_freqs`? If you repeat the ANALYZE do you still get similar results?

Comment: @jjanes Hmm, how can I check for the *true* `n_distinct`? Stats target is the default 100. Will update my answer will all `most_common_freqs`. Repeating `ANALYZE` gives similar results, yeah.

Comment: I think I made a mistake here. The index actually contains `meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid' IS NOT NULL` clause for the field (I was testing with different approaches and got it mixed up) and according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44626194/165629 partial indexes are not used in row count estimates. If I add the same index without the `IS NOT NULL` clause, then row count estimates get corrected. This makes me wonder, if partial index always needs a non-partial index counterpart (with JSONB, as the indexed column by default does not have stats), or rather just full index always...

Comment: Just FYI, the real ndistinct could be obtained from `select count(distinct meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid') from node` or `select count(*) from (select meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid' from node group by 1) f`.  But we don't need to know that anymore.

Comment: Ah, you meant that, of course. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, you really have a *partial* expressional index, and partial indexes are (sadly) not used in estimation.  Which explains why I couldn't replicate the issue at first as I was not testing with partial.

> This makes me wonder, if partial index always needs a non-partial index counterpart

I think this ponder only makes sense in the context of partial *expressional* indexes.  And still, I'd answer 'no' to the 'always' part. The main reason to have an expressional index is usually to have a usable index on the expression that the planner can choose to use.  And the main reason to have it partial is to save space and maintenance.  Usually the existing stats are good enough to make the choice.  It is not common for the additional stats to be the main or only reason for the index to exist.  In the specific case you described, of the WHERE being a condition over the same expression as is being indexed, then if you did build the full index to get the stats usage, then also having the partial no longer makes sense.  It takes up even more space, and can't do anything the full can't do just as well.

And in v14, you can now collect stats on an expression without even having the expressional index at all--making that use case even rarer.

```
create statistics blahblahblah on ((meta ->> 'group_owner_uuid')) from node;
```

So in your case, after an upgrade you could still have the index be partial to save space, and use the `create statistics` to get the better estimate, if you do happen to need both.

Comment: Indeed, I think I will need to go with full index now but good to know about v14 improvement. I tried partial indexes now, because disk space savings were enormous on fields that rarely exist. On my DB, indexing a JSONB field, that never exists, takes 183MB of space, while full GIN index on the JSONB column takes 1297MB. That seems a lot for data which doesn't actually exist. Especially, considering the recent improvements on saving disk space on duplicate values (although I guess that only concerns _actual_ values).

Comment: Postgres v14 will actually be really, _really_ nice here, as I can just GIN index the full JSONB column (I already have that) and then calculate statistics for the most commonly used fields, so the query planner knows to better _use that index_. Sure, the generic index won't be as fast as specialized expression indexes here, but it will probably be sufficient for me, as the biggest pain (I think) is that due to hard-coded statistics, the query planner makes ugly choices (thinking it would retrieve lots and lots of rows for a query that would actually return only a few, thus skipping the index)